# I loved a man from a far but he's passed away, would I be able to be his wife in Jannah?

Tags: nikah, jannah, love

I loved a man from a far but he's passed away, he never knew about me or my feelings and I never acted upon those feelings. He was unmarried and He had righteous character and I fell for him because of that, I do not plan on getting married in this life and I've been praying to Allah, wishing to be with the man I love in the after life. Will I be able to be his wife if I pray and ask Allah and remain unmarried and protect my chaste/purity?
*(please do not give comments such as "Work your way into Jannah first." because I'm trying my best to get there..please don't shut my question away..)*
also please provide proof as well if you're able to and thank you all for reading this, jazakallah khair.

Comment: Their seem to be some evidences that a wife of a man in this life may be his wife in the hereafter. I've not come across anything which addresses your topic so far.

Comment: There’s a few issues in your question that potentially contradict each other. If you are in Jannah, then you will be satisfied, regardless of whatever earthly desire you might have had. Secondly, what if the man doesn’t desire you? You want Allah to force someone into being with you? Anyways, your hypothesis includes already being in Jannah - that is more than enough to conclude that you won’t be sad, depressed or having certain unsatisfied emotions. Which is the notion that creeps into your question; unfulfillment - a notion that goes against the concept of Jannah.